# Different routes?

Tags: routes, google-distancematrix-api

I'm working with the Google distance API. We had a user report the mileage of a round-trip that's wrong. When I investigated I notice it routes them one way going from A to B then a different going from B to A. Why does that happen?

Here's the addresses: A - 45 Constitution Blvd, Kutztown, PA 19530 / B - 1105 Bethlehem Pike, Sellersville, PA 18960

A to B = 36.6 miles / B to A = 39.7 miles

There are no one way roads so the same route is possible in both directions. I would expect to see it as 36.6 miles both ways. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe B to A is with traffic jam and it takes detour

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. The search returns this regardless of the traffic. I ran it at midnight over the week-end with the same results.